# Integer pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers, serial-port

I am working with doing some serial communications in C in Linux. I am doing this using file descriptors. For some reason after `char* s = "Hello world"`, I can write `s` to the serial port using the write method, no problem. I am using a serial monitor program to check the other end. However, I cannot send any other sort of data. I get a "Bad Address" error from the write function.

However, I noticed that if I did something very strange: `int* x = "5";` That I could then send this `x`. My question is, what in the world does `int* x = "5"` mean?

Comment: `int *x = "5"` declares `x` as a pointer to an integer that resides at the beginning of the string `"5"`.  When you write it, it probably prints the `5`, a null character, and whatever the next two bytes happen to be, assuming `sizeof(int) = 4` on your platform.

Comment: @AdamLiss no, he said "5" not 5.

Comment: @SethCarnegie No, he said `5` and then edited his question to say `"5"`, and then I updated my comment.  :-)

Comment: @AdamLiss ah, he must have edited it quickly enough that the edit was collapsed into the original question

Comment: You should compile with stricter warnings, e.g. `-Wall -Werror` when using GCC. If you do that, `int *x = "5"` won't pass.

Answer (score 3):

```
int* x = "5";
```

This is not valid C code. You have to cast the value of the array to an `int *` but a dereference of the pointer can still break alignment rules and be undefined behavior.

```
int *x =  (int *) "5";
```

This last code stores an unnamed array object of type `char [2]`. The value of `"5"` is a pointer to its first element, the pointer is a `char *`. The cast converts the `char *` to an  `int *` and stores it in `x`.

Comment: isn't it allowed to cast a `char*` to anything? (according to C aliasing rules)

Comment: @moooeeeep there is no violation of aliasing, but pointers may not have the same alignment requirements.

Answer (score 2):

```
int* x = "5";
```

is a *constraint violation*.  That means that any conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic for it.  It needn't be treated as a fatal error; a compiler is allowed to issue a warning and then successfully translate the program.  But the language does not define the behavior of this declaration.

There is no implicit conversion from `char*` (the type of `"5"` after it decays) to `int*`.

This is as close as C gets to saying that something is illegal.

In practice, compilers that accept this declaration will probably treat it as equivalent to:

```
int *x = (int*)"5";
```

i.e., they'll insert a conversion.  (This isn't the only possible interpretation, but most compilers will either interpret it this way or reject it.)  This takes the `char*` value that results from the decay of the array expression `"5"` (i.e., the address of the `'5'` character at the beginning of the string), and converts to `int*`.

The resulting `int*` pointer points to an `int` object that may or may not be valid.  The string `"5"` is two bytes long (`{ '5', '\0' }`).  If `int` is two bytes, `*x` may evaluate to the result of interpreting those two bytes as an `int` value -- which will depend on the system's endianness.  Or, if the string literal isn't correctly aligned for an `int` object, evaluating `*x` might terminate your program.  And if `int` is wider than two bytes (as it very commonly is), `*x` refers to memory past the end of the string literal.  In any case, attempting to modify `*x` has yet another kind of undefined behavior, since attempting to modify a string literal is explicitly undefined.

You should have gotten at least a warning when you compiled that declaration.  If so, you definitely should not have ignored it.  If you didn't get a warning, you should find out how to coax your compiler to produce more warnings.

TL;DR: Don't do that.

Comment: Wow thanks. Yeah, I really was not expecting it to compile, and when it did I was thoroughly confused. I was just wondering what this actually meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`int* x = "5"` implicitly casts `"5"` (a `const char*`) to an `int*` and stores it in `x`.  Thus, `x` will point to `sizeof(int)` bytes in which the lowest is 0x35 (the character '5'), the next is 0, and the rest are indeterminate and will lead to undefined behavior when read.

Comment: Not to mention he's using a crappy compiler that lets `char const[2]` be implicitly convertible to `int*`

Comment: Actually, `"5"` is a `char[]`, not a `const char*`, even though you should use it as if it were `const`.

Comment: He's probably using a crappy compiler that lets `char*` be implicitly convertible to `int*`; the expression `"5"` decays to `char*` in most contexts.

Comment: whoa whoa, gcc isnt a crappy compiler guys.